# How can I import and use the functionality of a plain JavaScript file in my Angular 5 (CLI) project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have searched high and low and tried various solutions for hours, but cannot seem to come right with this issue: I am trying to use a plain `JavaScript` file with an `Angular 5` project, created with the `Angular CLI`.

I have tried various `import` methods, I have tried `"allowJs": true`, I have tried `exports` and a bunch of other stuff. And to no avail!

Please help me: How can I import and use the functionality of a `.js` file in my Angular 5 project? Could you please list step for step what to do.

**Please Note:** It is not a package I could install via npm or something like that. It is an external library that is not available via npm.

**UPDATE:** I have tried declaring my `Xcelcious.Common.js` file in my `index.html` as one normally would do `<script type="text/javascript" src="Xcelcious.Common.js"></script>`, and I have used `import` to try and make use of the functionality:

```
import { Xcelcious } from '../../Xcelcious.Common.js';

declare let Xcelcious: any;
```

**But I get the following error when I compile my project:** ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(4,27): error TS6143: Module '../../Xcelcious.Common.js' was resolved to 'C:/Apps/CordovaApps/BoilerplateApp2/ngCordova/src/Xcelcious.Common.js', **but '--allowJs' is not set.**

**I have set "allowJs": true in my tsconfig.jason, but get this error when I compile:** ERROR in error TS5055: Cannot write file 'C:/Apps/CordovaApps/BoilerplateApp2/ngCordova/src/Xcelcious.Common.js' because it would overwrite input file.
  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files.

**This is what my tsconfig.json looks like:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "allowJs":true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is an example of my `Xcelcious.Common.js` file:**

```
Xcelcious = {
  ApiURL: "http://localhost:100/api",
  IsMobile: false,
  SimulateMobile: true,
  Camera: {
    PhotoFromLibrary: function (success, fail) {
      if (Xcelcious.IsMobile || Xcelcious.SimulateMobile) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          //targetWidth: 1024,
          //targetHeight: 768,
          correctOrientation: true,
          allowEdit: false,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
      } else {
        //TODO: Add camera for browser
      }
    },
    PhotoFromCamera: function (success, fail) {
      if (Xcelcious.IsMobile || Xcelcious.SimulateMobile) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          //targetWidth: 1024,
          //targetHeight: 768,
          correctOrientation: true,
          allowEdit: false,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
        });
      } else {
        //TODO: Add camera for browser
      }
    }
 }
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: *Could you please list step for step what to do* - you can start with providing more details what exactly is this JS file and how you expect it to work together with Angular app. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was quite simple (in hind sight!). It is pretty much what @Wesley Coetzee said in his answer, but had to add the reference to my `scripts` `array` in `.angular-cli.jason`.

**So this everything I had to do to make it work** (my custom JavaScript file is called `test.js`):

1. In my `index.html` I had to reference my script `<script src="app/test.js">`
2. In my `.angular-cli.json` I had to reference my script `"scripts": ["app/test.js"],`
3. In the `component` I wished to use the `test.js` script functionality, I had to add `declare let test: any;`(directly under my `imports`)
4. I could then use the functionality by calling `test.alert();`

**NOTE:** In my case I had a simple `JavaScript object` as my functionality in the script. Example:

```
test = {
  alert: function () {
    alert('Alert!');
  },
  newAlert: function () {
    alert('New Alert!');
  }
};
```

**To make this approach work, I had to explicitly `declare` `test` (point no 3) as my variable (`let`) to access the code in the `.js` file, as this was the name of my `JavaScript` `object`.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are using webpack or systemjs.

Make sure you are getting your `.js` file link injected into your main index.html page, as you would normally add a js file library to your index.html page.

To use the function(s) from the js file, you do the following, I will use `jQuery` as an example.

To make use of the `$` from jQuery you will add

```
import { ... } from '...';

declare let $: any;

@Component({ ... })
export class MyClass { ... }
```

The `declare let $: any;` at the top allows you to use `$` inside that component. This will also avoid any `tslint` errors as well.

That can be used with other libraries such as `momentjs`, etc.

EDIT:

So you are using Webpack.

Inside your `index.html` add the following:

```
<script src="./path to js/Xcelcious.Common.js"></script>
```

Inside your component you do not need `import { Xcelcious } from '../../Xcelcious.Common.js';`.

Doing the `declare let Xcelcious: any;` should allow you to access methods of `Xcelcious`, for example `Excelcious.IsMobile`.

Comment: Hi Wesley, thank you for your response. I am using webpack (standard Angular CLI generated project). I did exactly as you explained (see my notes on my question on things tried), but get the error `ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(4,27): error TS6143: Module '../../Xcelcious.Common.js' was resolved to 'C:/Apps/CordovaApps/BoilerplateApp2/ngCordova/src/Xcelcious.Common.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.`. See my other comments on my question update.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hey Wesley. I think you missed omething in your update. It is not very clear what I must do in the index.html. Also, do I simply delete the import of the .js file, and only use declare?

Comment: You're right, I forgot the code tags for the line in the index.html. Yes remove the import of the js file and only use the declare. Adding the js library to the index.html makes it available throughout the entire solution

Comment: Hi Wesley. I got the app to build, but cannot find my external `.js` code in Chrome debugging. I removed the `"allowJs": true` because of the errors, and I am using only the reference of the `.js` file in the `index.html`, and using the `declare let Xcelcious: any;` Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What functions does this library provide? For example, `momentjs` is used as follows: `moment(date).format();` So at the top I would use `declare let moment: any;`

Comment: i have created even a very simple file as a test with the following: `test = {
  alert: function(){
    return alert('Alert!');
  }
};`, and when I try to run `test.alert();` in my `onInit()` I get no result or alert. So I have `declare let test: any;` The error I get is `test is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

In your component you can simply import your plain js file and declare your external object:

```
import 'external.js'
declare var myExtObject: any;
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. I have tried this. See my updated question for more details on what I have tried.